# Fiddler session Hidden due to FTS>Path

Tags: fiddler

I'm running Fiddler for .Net 4.6.1 v5.0.20202.18177

In the Fiddler options dialog I have "Caputre HTTPS CONNECTs", and "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" enabled"

I have Postman installed on the same machine, with Fiddler set as its proxy. I make a https call to a cloud web service from Postman. I see a session row in Fiddler with a Host of "Tunnel to" that hits the URL of the web service.

If I select Help\Troubleshoot from Fiddler then it also shows the "real" session with the request and response payloads. If I right-click the "real" (filtered) session and select "Comment" then the following is displayed, repeated many times:

"Hidden due to FTS>Path"

I'm trying to prevent this "real" session being filtered. I've checked the filters at the bottom left of the Fiddler screen and none of them match. I don't have the filters tab enabled.

How can I prevent my "real" session from being filtered?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you entered any host on the HTTPS option tab in the section "Skip decryption for the following hosts"? Is Fiddler configured to capture traffic from "All processes" (see status at the bottom first entry on the left side).

Comment: Hi, I've added screenshots to show that "All Processes" is set. None of the filters shown in blue relate to the target url I'm trying to trace for - which I do see in strikethrough text when Troubleshooting is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I did have a filter set, I just couldn't see it because it was off the bottom of the screen. I didn't see a vertical scrollbar but I discovered that filters can be removed by right-clicking their name. So, I right clicked about 30 times in order to remove all filters - then I could see my traced request again.

Comment: This is a feature of an add-on right? because in plain Fiddler you don't have a Filter list where you can remove entries.

Comment: I haven't installed any add-ons, just downloaded latest version and installed from the msi.

Comment: I still don't understand how you saved the filters so that they appear at the bottom of the screen. What function have you used to create such a filter?

Comment: I haven't used any custom function. With the latest version, the filters are added to the list at the bottom of the screen each time I right-click a session and select "Filter Now". It seems to be a nice feature because it remembers your filters for the next time you load Fiddler :)

Answer (score 0):

FTS stands for Filter Troubleshooting and "FTS>Path" means that you have a Path filter (i.e. Hide '/xxxxx/') that is filtering the request.

I suspect there's not a lot of room for error here, there can be a vertical scrollbar and unless there is Unicode or symbol trickery, it seems pretty straightforward.